# Wordpress custom css in head

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to add page specific css in the head. For some reason the page completely goes white when I use the code below:

```
<?php if (is_page(5)) {
        <style>
        </style>
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<style>` is not right PHP syntax. Try this:

---

```
<?php if (is_page(5)) { ?>
    <style>
    </style>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: You nailed it in one. Thanks for the quick response Sebastian!